# Flask howto fill input field with informations selected in SelectField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

i got two forms in one HTML Document which should interact with another. The user can select one option in the SelectionField and the Details should appear on the Input fields ready for edit. How can i populate the input fields? Is this possible without reloading the the page?

forms.py

```
class Form1(FlaskForm):
    select = SelectField('Test', choices=[], coerce=str)
    submit = SubmitField('Get Data')

class Form2(FlaskForm):
    field1 = StringField('field1', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

app.py

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    test = ["1", "2", "3"]
    form1 = Form1()
    form1.select.choices = test
    form2 = Form2()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form1.select.data:
            print(form1.select.data)
    return render_template('index.html', form1=form1, form2=form2)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {{ form1.select(size="30") }}
        {{ form1.submit }}
    </form>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {{ form2.field1.label }}
        {{ form2.field1 }}
        {{ form2.submit }}
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need a little bit of javascript, add a button to toggle `hidden` for the forms. check this one https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: Thx but i do not wanna hide anythin. After select and submit there will be a sql query and the details should appear in the input fields, the user can edit and submit to the database again.

Comment: okay understood, you need create the specific APIs and whenever any input field is in `focus` call the api and populate, you need javascript for that, you can use `fetch` (easy) or `XMLHttpRequest`(ugly) for that with some basic DOM manipulation.

Comment: Is there no way to get the Data at the Part of print(form1.select.data)? There will be the SQL Query where i get the Details for the selected Option. Goal is to populate all fields at once after. If its easier to reload the Page after its also "ok"